# how to search in array of document ids in firestore using java for android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Java for android app development and my app is connected with firestore I am trying to create a favorite list of product documents by storing document IDs in shared preferences as Set of String ids
but unfortunately, I don't know how to retrieve documents related to my favorite list
I searched for a long time but all results deal with fields of document not or only one document id not list of document ids
this is my code and hope to find an answer to write the correct condition

```
SharedPreferences sharedFile = favorite.this.getSharedPreferences("appShared", favorite.this.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Set<String> favList=sharedFile.getStringSet("fav_products",new HashSet<String>());


        firestore.collection("products").get()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: hello @AlexMamo my question is not related to the structure of data base I want all documents of a collection with an array of document ID  my issue is the where condition only

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "all documents of a collection with an array of document ID my issue is the where condition only"?